AWS EC2 : Ubuntu npm warn tar TAR_BAD_ARCHIVE: Unrecognized archive format
Server : AWS EC2 Ubuntu
NPM Install suddenly throwing error for Ubuntu Server and also for AWS code build server (ubuntu)
Error :
npm warn tar TAR_BAD_ARCHIVE: Unrecognized archive format
This is due to ubuntu ?
Working good for EC2- AMAZON Linux 2023

mumbai region only facing this issue
npm team identified this issue :  Investigating - We are currently investigating failures to install packages due to TAR_BAD_ARCHIVE or 304 Not Modified responses for clients in Mumbai, India.

https://github.com/mafintosh/fs-constants/issues/2#issuecomment-2548144646 plz check this works for me.
Facing same issue, it was wroking fine suddenly it throws error
Error : npm warn tar TAR_BAD_ARCHIVE: Unrecognized archive format
platform:EC2- AMAZON Linux 2023

https://github.com/mafintosh/fs-constants/issues/2#issuecomment-2548144646 plz check this work for me

Guy's we found the answer run this command above the npm install
RUN npm config set registry https://registry.npmmirror.com/ --global
step1: config set registry https://registry.npmmirror.com/ --global
step2: npm install
step3: npm start

the error is now fixed I guess, as it is working on our deployment without implementing any alternate fixes

Thank you all for the support..!
AWS EC2 Mumbai Region issues resolved .
We are able to deploy the code successfully without any additional fixes.
